# Cygwin Gcc error while loading shared libraries?

Tags: cygwin

I have instaled Cygwin after running MinGW for a while now. But when I try to compile the console gives me:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/cc1.exe: error while loading shared libraries: ?: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

What does this mean?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I have the same problem and I found the solution.

According to the FAQ of Cygwin

> Q: Why is C:\cygwin\usr\bin invisible from windows?
>
> A: Because **it does not really exist**.  In cygwin,  /usr/bin is just a link to /bin.

So trying to add "C:\cygwin\usr\bin" to PATH will be in vain.

Add "C:\cygwin64\bin" to PATH instead. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Raku Escape's solution was working for me, after I close Eclipse and reimported the project. (so that the PATH modification are taken into account)

Answer (score 9):

You are missing a library, please run `cygcheck /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/cc1.exe` or `ldd /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/cc1.exe` to see what is the missing library.

Comment: You might have to reinstall some cygwin packages maybe. As said [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/77779/relationship-between-cc1-and-gcc)  :
"`cc1.exe` is the internal command which takes preprocessed C-language files and converts them to assembly.".

Comment: Try to reinstall the packages : `libgcc1` and `gcc-core`. Might solve this.

Answer (score 1):

(I'd rather ask a question in the comments first, but I don't have enough reputation yet.)

Your `cc1` is unable to load some DLLs it needs to start. Looking at the Cygwin source code, this can be either a library specified in `LD_PRELOAD`, or -- more probably -- a library the executable depends on. The `?` in the error message seems to be the default return value of `find_first_notloaded_dll` (`hookapi.cc`), in case the function can't determine what library is missing.

To diagnose the issue, I suggest checking your `PATH` variable (or even clearing it of any non-Cygwin paths and trying the compilation again) and/or using [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to find the missing DLLs (start it from a Cygwin shell, so it can see the same `PATH`). `ldd` (included with Cygwin) may also give some clues, but I wouldn't bet on it.

It's possible a clean re-install of Cygwin will be necessary to solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I also came this error on windows machine while executing `.exe` file generated by `scilab2C` i.e toolbox for `Scilab`

For `Windows 32 bit` Add the environment variable path as follow :

```
C:\cygwin\usr\i686-pc-cygwin\bin
```

Hope so this will solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Adding some background info. I had the same problem when building my own program and linking it against graphviz cgraph.dll. Turns out this is related to where windows searches for DLLs (see here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7d83bc18.aspx) So adding the path of your missing library to PATH should fix the problem.

It is unfortunate that the message doesn't include the name of the library. Luckily cmd.exe DOES give you this name (so it's good for something after all;)

Answer (score 0):

Are you including the path to your lib directory?
Looks like you are not

I'm not very familiar with Cygwin, I mainly use MinGW, but I think the error message speaks for itself

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, you are simply missing /usr/bin in the PATH variable. 
Adding 'export PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH' to your .bashrc file will solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just had this problem trying to compile a package with make and it wanted some cygguile dll file that was just installed along with make.

My solution was I had not only migrated my cygwin64 directory across drives because the sector sizes were mismatched for some reason even though the drivers were both under 2TB and should have been using 512 byte sector sizes.. So I had to install a new system and move files over there, might have had weird permissions on them.

Also had to patch cygwin1.dll end of Jan 2020 because of a recent input problem in ConEmu with Windows 10 1903 build, but just did it again with this working so that doesn't seem to be the issue.

Reinstalling cygwin by deleting that entire directory, taking ownership of it first.., seemed to work now...

Answer (score 0):

if you have both mingw and cygwin in your system,In the environment variable remove all mingW and just add C:\cygwin64\bin in both system varaible and user variable